# Any keyboard shortcut for "Back" in Chromium browser?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, chromium

Is there a keyboard shortcut for "Back" in Chromium browser?  I thought the Backspace key usually works, but it doesn't.  On Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Does Alt+right arrow work?

Comment: No, but Alt+left arrow does!  ;)

Comment: @Norbert, Wim: One of you should put that as an answer.

Comment: I was not sure about that since I use Google Chrome on Windows.

Comment: There is a chromium extension for enabling the backspace key: http://askubuntu.com/a/347849/250556

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use Alt+left as keyboard shortcut for "Back".

Comment: And alt+right for forward

Comment: Might only work with the left Alt key.

Comment: works with both the Alt keys :)

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 11.10 <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> turns up volume and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> turns it down and this is the default accounting to the shortcut menu. It would have to be custom made by either overriding those shortcuts or making your own.

Personally I feel the backspace when cursor is not in an editable text field would be a better option to go back.

Comment: Did you mean to put left twice?